# Can I limit the scope of Javascript's Array.prototype extensions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I'd like to limit the scope of extending Array

```
Array.prototype.myExtension = function() { 
// do something;
// return something;
};
```

to the current JS module. This extension should be invisible in other modules.

Comment: No you can't, for all intents and purposes, this is the same as creating a global variable

Answer (score 0):

The workarounds are to sandbox an Array in another scope (an iframe or web worker) or to define the method generically and **call** it (or **apply**) with an array object.

```
modulenamespace.myExtension = function() { 
// do something;
// return something;
}


modulenamespace.myExtension.call(array)
```